# Way to pass JavaScript variable to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Is JSON the unic way to pass variable from JavaScript to Django and Django JavaScript?

Thank you

Comment: You need to expand this question. In it's current form it makes no sense.

Comment: The answer is both yes and know depending on what you are trying to do and what you are using. You need to explain what you want in more depth for anyone to answer your question in a way that will work for you.

Comment: Things like are you using a JavaScript framework, do you want the page to refresh or not, is it form data, do you want the result be be reproduced by a link, are you using something like DRF, etc..

Comment: In any case you'll have to make a HTTP REQUEST to django back-end to send the 'VALUE' (not variable) with Django.